# JAVA JDBC - fallo intermitente no me lo explico

Tags: java, jdbc

Hola estoy trabajando de Eclipse a Oracle con JDBC, y tengo el siguiente error:

2022-06-03 12:42:36 ERROR GestionTrenes:141 - ORA-00001: unique constraint (HR.SYS_C0034274) violated

En el siguiente código:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO reservas (ID_RESERVA, NIF, ID_TRAYECTO_DIARIO, BILLETES) VALUES (seq_reservas.nextval, ?, ?, ?)";
            pstmt_reserva = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt_reserva.setString(1, m_NIF_cliente);
            pstmt_reserva.setInt(2, id_trayecto_diario);
            pstmt_reserva.setInt(3, n_billetes);
            pstmt_reserva.executeUpdate();
```

LA cosa es que da el fallo un número de veces y alguna vez lo hace bien.

Hay otra forma de establecer la primary key, para que genere una nueva cada vez que se ejecuta la función?
O viene de otro lado el error?

Comment: *`unique constraint (HR.SYS_C0034274) violated`* significa que estás intentando insertar un registro que viola una restricción de unicidad, o lo que es lo mismo, intentas insertar un registro que sería duplicado.

Comment: hay otra manera de establecer la clave primaria?, creo que sera ese el valor que estará calculando mal.

Comment: Has insertado valores "manualmente", es decir, en la base de datos sin usar la secuencia?

Comment: Puede ser la PK o puede ser otra restricción del tipo `UNIQUE`, podrás saberlo revisando cómo tienes creada la tabla. Puedes escribir en el SGBD la instrucción `DESC reservas;` y te mostrará cómo está creada tu tabla, qué restricciones tiene, etc.

Comment: a lo de los valores... si, hice alguna prueba. pero entiendo que al ejecutar hava se reinicia todo no? Miedo me da, pero hago un drop desde oracle a todas las tablas a ver?

Comment: Sin descripción de la tabla, sus campos y constraints, complicado adivinar

Comment: El problema es que estas insertando en la tabla registros con el mismo campo ID